# Link tokens required on Avg for random number generation

Tags: chainlink, randomness, random, vrf

Can someone tell how much link tokens are required on an avg. to generate random number via VRF chainlink method??

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer. Determining an average would depend on the gas costs of the chain being used.

[Chainlink VRFv2 - How is gas cost determined?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/chainlink-vrfv2-how-is-gas-cost-determined)